# Why does New-AzureRmVM give entity name error?

Tags: regex, azure, azure-powershell

When I run this code from PowerShell ISE

```
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $VM
```

I get this error

```
New-AzureRmVM : The entity name is invalid according to its validation rule: ^[^_\W][\w-._]{0,79}(?<![-.])$.
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
OperationID : 'my-operation-id'
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $VM
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

$ResourceGroupName contains my resource group name, "foobar.com" in this example.

$Location contains "East US 2".

$VM contains my VM config below

```
ResourceGroupName        : 
Id                       : 
Name                     : foobar
Type                     : 
Location                 : 
Tags                     : null
AvailabilitySetReference : null
DiagnosticsProfile       : {
                             "bootDiagnostics": {
                               "enabled": true,
                               "storageUri": "https://foobar.blob.core.windows.net/"
                             }
                           }
Extensions               : null
HardwareProfile          : {
                             "vmSize": "Basic_A0"
                           }
InstanceView             : null
NetworkProfile           : {
                             "networkInterfaces": [
                               {
                                 "properties.primary": null,
                                 "id": "/subscriptions/my-sub-id/resourceGroups/foobar.com/providers/Microsoft.Network/n
                           etworkInterfaces/foobar"
                               }
                             ]
                           }
OSProfile                : {
                             "computerName": "foobar",
                             "adminUsername": "admin",
                             "adminPassword": "password",
                             "customData": null,
                             "windowsConfiguration": {
                               "provisionVMAgent": true,
                               "enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
                               "timeZone": "UTC-05:00",
                               "additionalUnattendContent": null,
                               "winRM": null
                             },
                             "linuxConfiguration": null,
                             "secrets": null
                           }
Plan                     : null
ProvisioningState        : 
StorageProfile           : {
                             "imageReference": {
                               "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                               "offer": "WindowsServer",
                               "sku": "Windows-Server-Technical-Preview",
                               "version": "latest"
                             },
                             "osDisk": {
                               "osType": null,
                               "encryptionSettings": null,
                               "name": "OS Disk",
                               "vhd": {
                                 "uri": "https://foobar.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/foobar-os.vhd"
                               },
                               "image": null,
                               "caching": null,
                               "createOption": "fromImage",
                               "diskSizeGB": null
                             },
                             "dataDisks": [
                               {
                                 "lun": 0,
                                 "name": "Data Disk",
                                 "vhd": {
                                   "uri": "https://foobar.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/foobar-data.vhd"
                                 },
                                 "image": null,
                                 "caching": null,
                                 "createOption": "empty",
                                 "diskSizeGB": 20
                               }
                             ]
                           }
DataDiskNames            : {Data Disk}
NetworkInterfaceIDs      : {/subscriptions/my-sub-id/resourceGroups/foobar.com/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterf
                           aces/foobar}
```

Can anyone please tell me what the entity name it is referring to is? Is it the name of the VM, the name of one of the storage locations, etc?
As far as I can tell, everything matches the regex so I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Googling the command name only brings up a few hits, and none mention anything about entity names at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out through trial and error. Data and OS disks apparently can't have spaces in the name. It would've helped if the Azure PS module was better documented.

Comment: Will you  [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the checkmark.